# How to get position from onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecylerView adapter where I am handling onClicks in the onCreateViewHolder method, however I cannot figure out a way to get the current position. My current method looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_small, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView, new ViewHolder.IViewHolderClicks() {
            @Override
            public void onImage(ImageView image) {
                // Need the position for logic in here
                // for example, myArrayList.get(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

Does anybody know how to access the current position from within onCreateViewHolder?

Comment: If I stored the position in a class member variable and assigned it in the onBindViewHolder method would that be a reliable method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onClick handler, call viewHolder.getAdapterPosition().

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_small, parent, false);

    final ViewHolder vh = ViewHolder(itemView, new ViewHolder.IViewHolderClicks() {
        @Override
        public void onImage(ImageView image) {
            int position = vh.getAdapterPosition();
        }
    });
    return vh;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that before but I always get the error that the ViewHolder may not have been initialised yet.

Comment: can you make IViewHolderClicks() a setter instead of a constructor parameter ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update! But I made it a setter and it worked fine!

Comment: I am getting position -1, Please help me

Answer (score 2):

`onCreateViewHolder()` is not the proper place to store the position. When the ViewHolder gets recycled, you will not get another call to `onCreateViewHolder()`, so you will not have a chance to "fix" the position when the ViewHolder is recycled.

You can instead do this in `onBindViewHolder()`, which gives you the position as one of its arguments and is called each time the ViewHolder is recycled.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, I will try this and see if it works! Cheers!

Comment: Don't add listener in onBindViewHolder because that position may change without rebinding the view.